# Ctrl+RightArrow in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text, I've noticed that pressing `Ctrl+RightArrow` will sometimes tab through code, but other times it'll duplicate my mouse cursor. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there any duplicate key sequences in your keymap?

Comment: @MaartenDev I'm using default settings for everything, it's a fresh install and I haven't fiddled with it

Answer (score 0):

This are the default keybindings for `ctrl+right`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+right"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+j", "ctrl+right"], "command": "unselect_to_right" },
```

The only ways I know to duplicate the cursor is `shift+rightclickdrag`, `ctrl+click` and `alt+shift+up/down`.